# What is difference between URL,URI,URN and QueryString

Tags: url, uri, query-string

Difference between URL,URI,URN and Query String and their  in .Net length.

Comment: Look here: [RFC 1738: Uniforn Resource Locators](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt),  [RFC 2141: Universal Resource Name Syntax](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2141.txt), [W3C Clarification: URIs, URLs and URNs](http://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/).  A "QueryString" is the syntax for an HTTP "GET" request, specified in [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).

Comment: @FoggyDay - no need to look anywhere else: As William pointed out, this is a duplicate question, fully answered elsewhere. Just vote to close this as    a duplicate.